# C program crashes when allocating compound structure

Tags: c, struct

OS: Windows 7, Compiler: GCC 3.2.3 (MinGW)

I have created those three data structures in C:

```
#define MAP_NAME_LEN    30
#define MAP_W           25
#define MAP_H           19
#define WORLD_W         32
#define WORLD_H         32

typedef unsigned char byte;

typedef struct Tile
{
    byte type;
    byte character;
    byte fgColor;
    byte bgColor;
};

typedef struct Map
{
    char name[MAP_NAME_LEN];
    Tile overlay[MAP_H][MAP_W];
    Tile underlay[MAP_H][MAP_W];
};

typedef struct World
{
    Map area[WORLD_H][WORLD_W];
};
```

When I try to create individual instances of Tile and/or Map, it's ok, no problem at all, everything works. But then if I try to create a World, like...

```
int main()
{
    World world;
}
```

...the program simply crashes (Windows 7 says that the program has crashed and is looking for a solution, etc). Do you guys have any idea why does that happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the values of `MAP_NAME_LEN`, `MAP_H` and `MAP_W`, `WORLD_H` and `WORLD_W`. Probably stack overflow.

Comment: What are MAP_W/H WORLD_W/H defined as? Perhaps you're putting too much on the stack?

Comment: you're using typedef without declaring a defintion. you should write it like this: typedef struct _Map {...} Map; you can also omit the _Map, to create anonymous struct if you prefer it like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the values of `MAP_NAME_LEN`, `MAP_H`, `MAP_W`, `WORLD_H`, and `WORLD_W`, you may have created a MASSIVE structure on the stack. Don't do that. The stack is relatively small, and generally cannot handle allocations of more than a few megabytes total (and often can only handle a few dozen kilobytes of allocation at a time). Given your constant values, you're likely to be running up against these limits - your `World` structure is nearly 4MB large, way too big to reasonably put on the stack.

So, instead, allocate it on the heap with `malloc`, or as a global or file-local static variable:

```
World world;

int main()
{
    /* ... */
}
```

or

```
int main()
{
    World *world = malloc(sizeof(*world));
    /* ... */
    free(world);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that your `World` object exceed the maximum stack size. It depends how you have defined `MAP_NAME_LEN`, `MAP_H`, `MAP_W` and `WORLD_H`, `WORLD_W`.

The total size of a `World` struct is at least: `WORLD_H * WORLD_W * (MAP_H * MAP_W * 2 * sizeof(Tile) + MAP_NAME_LEN)` (plus any padding the compiler might insert).

**Edit**

Now that you have added the constants you can calculate that your data structure will consume about 3.5MB (if `sizeof(Tile) == 4`). That is too much for the stack. The default stack size is usually about 1MB. Use `malloc` to allocate the data structure on the heap.

Comment: eh? why would tile's members be 32-bit aligned?

Comment: @bdonlan Many architectures require aligned memory access or incurr a penalty otherwise. A standard compiler optimization is to align struct members on 32bit (on a 32bit system)

Comment: I've never seen a compiler do that for `char`s (which that `byte` probably is a typedef for). And chances are the OP is on x86 (since he mentioned Windows 7), and the Windows x86 ABI does not align chars.

Comment: @bdonlan Mh, true - the padding usually comes in when you start mixing in larger types like `int`. I removed that part

Answer (score 1):

When you `typedef` a struct, you have to give a name, the syntax is `typedef struct foo { /* ... */ } Foo;` (the foo tag is optional).

**Edit** Now, with the sizes, it's very likely a stack overflow. A `Map` uses just short of 4KB, so a `World` comes close to 4MB. As far as I remember, Windows gives you only a smaller stack (methinks it was 1MB?).

Comment: This would not cause a crash.

Comment: In fact I'm compiling the program as C++ and the compiler does not complain about anything, it's just that for some reason the program crashes when I create a World instance. I'll try reducing the sizes of arrays and see if it still crashes, then I'll see whether it's due to stack overflow. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: @bdonlan Huh? The OP's code shouldn't even compile, much less run. How can use a typedef with no name? What would even be the point of that?

Comment: @Fernando If this is in a C++ codebase, you might want to point that out in your question.

Comment: @jlehr, unnamed typedefs are actually acceptable, at least in GCC: http://codepad.org/2dFxNsEj It's a bit pointless, but it's not causing the OP's program to crash at runtime, so this isn't answering the question.

Comment: @bdonlan ...but doesn't compile AT ALL in LLVM 3.0. The OP's question didn't specify the compiler technology.

Comment: @jlehr, sure, but the OP says it compiled and crashed at runtime. Anonymous typedefs may be a bad idea, but this belongs as a comment, _not_ an answer, because it is not causing the OP's problem.

Comment: @bdonlan Seems to me it's worse than pointless -- it's ambiguous when using `World` as a data type later on. What would that mean in GCC, I'm curious?

Comment: It's not ambiguous. GCC just treats it as an ordinary struct definition, it seems.

Comment: @FernandoAiresCastello C++ is a different beast, if you compile the code as such, it would probably be better to use the C++ tag.

Comment: @DanielFischer I guess I have to study more about C++ since I don't even know much about structs, I'm more used to classes.

Answer (score 1):

The [default stack size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks.aspx) (with VS2010 anyway) is 1MB.

`sizeof(World) == 3921920`, which is more than 3x greater than 1MB.

The crash you are seeing is a stack overflow.

You could try and increase the size of the stack (see link on how to do this) or allocate the `World` object on the heap.

Comment: Indeed, I just found out that by reducing the WORLD_H and WORLD_W both to 23 the program runs fine. If I increase these values then the stack overflows and the program crashes. So I just have to allocate a smaller "world" or like you said, increase the size of the stack or allocate it on the heap.